# An already Spoken to customer issue that has been resolved

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-tense

In a technical environment, what is the most suitable sentence to use when answering to someone about a problem that they had and we solved it for them:

1. The problem is solved
2. The problem has been solved

Comment: It's impossible to say without more context- each is appropriate in different cases.

Comment: so it is right to say "the problem is solved, kindly check your PC and let us know if you still face any problems"

Comment: In that instance I'd use "Your problem has been resolved, please check your PC and let us know if you have any more issues."

Answer (score 9):

**Both are correct.**

Notice the difference in tense.

"The problem **is** solved."   [*describes the current status of the problem*]

"The problem has been solved."  [*directly answers the question*   Has the problem been solved?]

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked if any new posts had been added after leaving mine sitting unsubmitted for over an hour.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in whether you want to emphasize the state of being solved or the action of solving.

"is solved" indicates that it is in the solved state.

"has been solved" indicates that the solving of the problem has been completed, which is really just what it means to be in the state of being "solved".

Comment: I am glad you see it the same way I do......

Answer (score 2):

Use either one. Both are correct. I would not use "resolved" here.  Google for "*solve or resolve*". [Here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=5796) is one explanation of their differences.  In short, you solve a problem and resolve a dispute.

Comment: It is not entirely as simple as that thread implies. One also resolve's confusion. Personally I would 'solve' a puzzle, or a maths  question, but I might 'resolve' the problem I had been having with my computer, or the strange noise in my car's engine.

Comment: You also resolve tickets in a bug tracking system which can be communicated as, "This issue has been resolved." But I'm not sure why this answer is mentioned "resolved" at all?