# Is "is sent" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

> File **is** sent.
>
> File **has been** sent.

Is the line above grammatically correct?
What is the correct one and what is the difference between both of them ?

Comment: Apart from the 'conversational deletion' (dropping the article; deletions don't subscribe to standard rules of grammar), this is a question about the be-perfect, and thus a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is correct: “I’m done” or “I have finished”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150661/which-is-correct-i-m-done-or-i-have-finished)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct: "is solved" or "has been solved"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155763/which-is-correct-is-solved-or-has-been-solved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the circumstances that you find both in.  In each case adding "The" to the front of the line would improve it, and the bottom line is certainly the easiest on the ears and rolls off the tongue.  However, as I assume this is being used with regards computing, the top line is shorter and does give the same impression to the computer savvy.

Answer (score 0):

Both these lines are correct but need 'A' and 'The' before them.

> **A** file is sent
>
> **The** file has been sent

Comment: If both listener and speaker know about which file they are talking about , "The file" is correct. We can also say A file has been sent. It is all related to content.

Answer (score -1):

after pressing the button a file is sent to the customer.
a file has been sent to the customer after he pressed the button.

The meaning is not the same.

Comment: This answer needs to be better stated. Can you explain which of the two OP's sentences is correct and why.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  Your answer needs explaining..